# Contract method works only with contract addresses and not regular account addresses

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, transactions

I've written a simple token contract for testing purposes:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract TestToken {
    uint public totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) public balanceOf;

    function transfer(address to, uint amount) public returns (bool) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= amount);
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balanceOf[to] += amount;
        return true;
    }

    function credit(address to, uint amount) public {
        balanceOf[to] += amount;
        totalSupply += amount;
    }

    function debit(address from, uint amount) public {
        balanceOf[from] -= amount;
        totalSupply -= amount;
    }
}
```

Whenever I call the `credit` method on the contract and pass the address of another contract as parameter, everything works as expected:

```
token.methods.credit(wallet._address, 500000).send({from: accounts[0], gas: "0xB3E4", gasPrice: "0x4A817C800", value: "0x"})
```

The status of the transaction is `0x1`.

The balance is updated:

```
token.methods.balanceOf(wallet._address).call()
'500000'
```

But when I pass the address of a regular ethereum account as a parameter, the transaction gets mined, but nothing happens.

```
token.methods.credit(accounts[0], 500000).send({from: accounts[0], gas: "0xB3E4", gasPrice: "0x4A817C800", value: "0x"})
```

The status of the transaction is `0x0`.

The balance doesn't change:

```
token.methods.balanceOf(accounts[0]).call()
'0'
```

---

Comparing the resulting signed transaction objects, the only difference other than the `data` field is that the signature `v` value is always `0` when the transaction fails and `1` when the transaction succeeds. But I'm not sure what that means.

---

**Update:**

Seems like it's not even contract vs non-contract, it's just that some addresses don't work.

For example, this works:

```
token.methods.credit('0xd2d0aD819B2679FBDD5C75F93fa13242bfd7E2A5', 500000000000000000).send({from: accounts[0], gas: "0xB3E4", gasPrice: "0x4A817C800", value: "0x"})
```

This doesn't:

```
token.methods.credit('0xc4beccd2ebdb32203800dfbc60ff0dd7c2762b48', 500000000000000000).send({from: accounts[0], gas: "0xB3E4", gasPrice: "0x4A817C800", value: "0x"})
```

Comment: One possible cause is that your gas is not enough to cover your transaction. A transaction will be cheaper is the recipient has a non-zero balance.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was, I did not account for the fact that if an account doesn't already have a balance it will cost more gas to create the balance mapping for that account. And so I was running out of gas when calling the method with new addresses.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most probably with gas limit.  How did you calculate it?

When transaction has some data attached, e.g. contract's method selector and parameters, zero bytes cost less than non-zero.  So, transaction that sends tokens to `0x0011223344556677889900112233445566778899` will cost less than transaction, that send the same number of tokens to `0x112233445566778899aa112233445566778899aa`.
Also, changing value in storage from zero to non-zero costs more, than changing it from non-zero to non-zero.  So `balanceOf[to] += amount;` costs less if `to` address already has some tokens.

Answer (score 0):

1. you're sending from account[0] to account[0], so the balance stays he same
2. if the balance of (accounts[0]) is zero, as you show in your second call, then transfer call will fail because of require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= amount)

Comment: Sorry I misstyped the question title, I was talking about the `credit` function which mints new tokens.